# grep or sed — need to extract a particular text

Tags: regex, shell, sed, grep

How would I extract only a substring of matched text.

I have an XML file with multiple lines. However this is what I am concerned with.

```
<url>/localhost/index.html</url>
```

I tried

```
cat file.txt | grep -o '<url>.*</url>'
```

It gave me the whole line. I only want `/localhost/index.html` to be printed. Is there any other option I could use like I know in Python you could group the regular expression into subgroups and pick the one you want to print.

Comment: XML file = XML parser

Comment: I do not want to use a parser I want a simple command line usage here. XML parser doesn't make sense when I want to do this on command line.  @ruakh

Comment: What @squiguy said has a large element of truth to it.  You can get away with regexes provided your XML is formatted so that they work, but if you had multiple `<url>...</url>` entries on a single line, for example, all the greedy-guts `.*` patterns in the answers would pick everything between the first `<url>` and the last `</url>` on the line.  If there was a newline between the `<url>` and the `</url>`, the regexes would miss that entry out altogether.  An XML parser would avoid all such problems.  So, be aware that regexes and XML or HTML are an uncomfortable fit in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `grep` does not support `-P` (see [ruakh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16744970/900873)), you can use `sed` to do it:

```
sed -n 's|.*<url>\(.*\)</url>.*|\1|p'
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what's happening here? It worked like a charm. Not sure what's happening here though.

Comment: `-n` cancels defaults `sed` output, then each time the given pattern have been matched he print the corresponding value catched inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, whenever you want "grep but only print out part of the match", `sed -n` is your friend.  `-n` says "don't print out every line by default".  `s|.*<url>\(.*\)</url>.*|\1|p` says "replace any entire line containing '<url>stuff</url>' with just the stuff between the <url> tags, and then print the line."  The replacement won't succeed on lines that don't match, so only those lines get printed, and only after it has done the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

If your version of `grep` supports the `-P` flag (for Perl-compatible regular expressions), you can use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
grep -Po '(?<=<url>).*(?=</url>)' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `sed`:

```
sed -n 's%.*<url>\(.*\)</url>.*%\1%p'
```

The `-n` option turns off the default printing.  The substitute command matches the `<url>` and `</url>` tags on a single line, captures what's in between and includes the leading and trailing material in the match.  The replacement is the captured material, and the `p` means print.  I used `%` in `s%%%` instead of `s///` because the `/` appears in the regex.  The alternative is to use slashes and escape the slash in the regex with a backslash.

Perl is also feasible and simple:

```
perl -n -e 'print if s%.*<url>(.*)</url>.*%\1%'
```

The `-n` creates a REPL except that it doesn't print by default; the `print` is only triggered if the substitute operation does a substitution.

And this slightly more sophisticated Perl script handles multiple `<url>...</url>` entries on a single line correctly:

```
perl -n -e 'print "$1\n" while (s%.*?<url>(.*?)</url>%%)'
```

It uses non-greedy regexes (`.*?`) to avoid eating too much information.  While the substitute operation detects and deletes a `<url>...</url>` with optional preceding garbage, the code prints the matched part between the URL markers followed by a newline.

Given the data:

```
xyz <url>/localhost/index1.html</url> pqr
xyz <url>/localhost/index2.html</url> abc <url>/localhost/index3.html</url> pqr
<url>/localhost/index4.html</url>
<url>/localhost/index5.html</url><url>/localhost/index6.html</url>
xyz <url>/localhost/index7.html</url> abc <url>/localhost/index3.html</url> xyz <url>/localhost/index9.html</url> abc <url>/localhost/index0.html</url> pqr
```

The last Perl script produces:

```
/localhost/index1.html
/localhost/index2.html
/localhost/index3.html
/localhost/index4.html
/localhost/index5.html
/localhost/index6.html
/localhost/index7.html
/localhost/index3.html
/localhost/index9.html
/localhost/index0.html
```